# Enter a string and add to a list every time a button is clicked, while displaying all strings entered

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, buttonclick

I am trying to create a Java program where you enter a word into a textfield, and click a button and the string is added to an output box.

I got that part, but I am trying to make it so that every time the button is clicked, a word gets added, and then all the words are listed in the output box.

I tried using Arrays and Arraylists with loops, but no success. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JTextArea result;
    // private String [] words;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Contructor
    public test() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Word:");
        add(label);

        textfield = new JTextField(15);
        add(textfield);

        button = new JButton("Add data to list");
        add(button);

        result = new JTextArea(10, 15);
        add(result);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                result.setText(textfield.getText());
                // int n = list.size();
                // for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
                // result.setText(list.get(i));
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // System.out.println("Hello");
        test gui = new test();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(200, 325);
        gui.setTitle("Title");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing now completely replaces the contents of the JTextArea with that of the JTextField, which is not what you want. You instead want to add the contents of `textfield` to what already exists in `result`, with something along the lines of:

```
result.setText(result.getText() + "\n" + textfield.getText());
```